# Loading JSON as Grails config

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I'm working on a Grails project that has a block of configuration that I would like to port to JSON.

The configuration encodes a javascript module dependency tree. For example, I might have a module `jquery-ui` that requires `jquery` and can be found at `{{web_root}}/jquery-ui.min.js`. That module depends on jQuery and other modules may depend on it. I would like to move this configuration (currently encoded in Groovy) to a format that can be consumed by [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/)-based build tools.

The most obvious way (to me) to solve this problem is to move the module tree into a JSON file that can be consumed by the build tools and the Grails app separately. I'm not experienced enough with Grails to know how to do such a thing; I know how to parse a JSON file, and I can figure out how to load a file, but I don't know what the "grails way" to solve this problem would be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A bit of thoughts [here](http://mbdgam.blogspot.ie/2013/05/a-way-to-integrate-gruntjs-in-grails.html).

Well I did always think that in this case you will have to ditch resources plugin all together and move all client resource processing to grunt/yo but problem is that you have to able to install npm in the build process otherwise the option is to process files before you build war which is not intuitive.

Also found this [grails-grunt-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/OverZealous/grails-grunt-plugin) but its not on grails plugins site.

And yes I know its not even an answer.